# How to remove rows from a table that exist in another table?

Tags: r

I have a table which consists of the best tennis players by ranking in the last 30 years. Example is below (height is not important for my question):

```
> head(mostSuccesfulPlayers)
    player_id    player_name player_ht
1      105453  Kei Nishikori       178
31     104925 Novak Djokovic       188
59     104731 Kevin Anderson       203
152    104745   Rafael Nadal       185
164    105227    Marin Cilic       198
172    103819  Roger Federer       185
```

I have another table which consists of basically all of the players in the data set, for example:

```
> head(allPlayers)
  player_id     player_name player_ht
1    100284   Jimmy Connors       178
2    100431 Mansour Bahrami       178
3    100529    Kevin Curren       185
4    100532     Johan Kriek       175
5    100553    Nduka Odizor       183
6    100581    John McEnroe       180
```

I want to create a table `notSoSuccesfulPlayers` which would consist of only the players from the `allPlayers` table, but without the players which are listed in the `mostSuccesfulPlayers` table. In the set theory notation, that would be `allPlayers` \ `mostSuccesfulPlayers`.

How can I do that? Huge thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: That sounds like an anti-join. Your two example tables don't have any overlapping players, though, so any suggestions people give based on those won't actually capture the task

Comment: @camille I just now realised that the heads of tables I displayed here contain all different players, but there were 110 players which were included in the `mostSuccessfulPlayers` table, and also in the `allPlayers` table. Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the canonical `setdiff`:

```r
subset(allPlayers, !player_id %in% mostSuccessfulPlayers$player_id)
```

Note: this works well when you can uniquely id each row by exactly one column; for multiple columns, you'll need `setdiff` (or `dplyr::anti_join`).

Comment: Thank you! This worked as it was possible to distinguish rows by `player_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and native R way would be function `setdiff`:

```
df = iris

df2 = df[1:100,]

setdiff(df, df2)
```

In your case

```
notSoSuccesfulPlayers  = setdiff(allPlayers, mostSuccesfulPlayers)
```